# Group data in a dataframe by cycles

Tags: r, dataframe

I have created a simplified version of my data:

```
a <- data.frame(a = c(0,1,2,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-2,-1,
                        0,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-2,-1,
                        0,1,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,2,1,
                        0,-1,-2,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,2,1,
                        0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-3,-2,-1,0))
a$b <- seq(1,length(a$a),1)
```

I try to detect the cycles in the data as the following (open to better suggestions):

```
library(quantmod)
max <- findPeaks(a$a)
min <- findValleys(a$a)
```

This actually gives be the point after the maximum and minimum. I want to find the span and set point of each cycle.

*cycle*: - The first cycle is defined as the first data point to the one before the first set point. For example, considering the first set point is -1.0, the first cycle is defined at rows 1 to 12. Row 12 is selected as the end of the cycle because it occurs after the first peak and valley and is also equal or smaller than -1.0. The second cycle starts at row 13 and goes to row 27, because row 27 is has an amplitude of 0 which is less than or equal to 0.5, and occurs after the second peak and valley points.:

```
span <- a[max-1,]$a-a[min-1,]$a
set <-  a[max,]$a - span/2
```

I want to group the data in the original dataframe `a` and assign the cycle number, span, and set point of each cycle (group) to the corresponding group of rows.

The desired output is:

```
> print(a)
    a  b cycles span   set
1   0  1      1    6 -1.0
2   1  2      1    6 -1.0
3   2  3      1    6 -1.0
4   3  4      1    6 -1.0
5   2  5      1    6 -1.0
6   1  6      1    6 -1.0
7   0  7      1    6 -1.0
8  -1  8      1    6 -1.0
9  -2  9      1    6 -1.0
10 -3 10      1    6 -1.0
11 -2 11      1    6 -1.0
12 -1 12      1    6 -1.0
13  0 13      2    7  0.5
14  1 14      2    7  0.5
15  2 15      2    7  0.5
16  3 16      2    7  0.5
17  4 17      2    7  0.5
18  3 18      2    7  0.5
19  2 19      2    7  0.5
20  1 20      2    7  0.5
21  0 21      2    7  0.5
22 -1 22      2    7  0.5
23 -2 23      2    7  0.5
24 -3 24      2    7  0.5
25 -2 25      2    7  0.5
26 -1 26      2    7  0.5
27  0 27      2    7  0.5
28  1 28      3    5 -1.5
29  2 29      3    5 -1.5
30  1 30      3    5 -1.5
31  0 31      3    5 -1.5
32 -1 32      3    5 -1.5
33 -2 33      3    5 -1.5
34 -3 34      3    5 -1.5
35 -2 35      3    5 -1.5
36 -1 36      4    6 -1.0
37  0 37      4    6 -1.0
38  1 38      4    6 -1.0
39  2 39      4    6 -1.0
40  3 40      4    6 -1.0
41  2 41      4    6 -1.0
42  1 42      4    6 -1.0
43  0 43      4    6 -1.0
44 -1 44      4    6 -1.0
45 -2 45      4    6 -1.0
46 -3 46      4    6 -1.0
47 -2 47      4    6 -1.0
48 -1 48      4    6 -1.0
49  0 49      5    7 -1.5
50  1 50      5    7 -1.5
51  2 51      5    7 -1.5
52  3 52      5    7 -1.5
53  2 53      5    7 -1.5
54  1 54      5    7 -1.5
55  0 55      5    7 -1.5
56 -1 56      5    7 -1.5
57 -2 57      5    7 -1.5
58 -3 58      5    7 -1.5
59 -4 59      5    7 -1.5
60 -3 60      5    7 -1.5
61 -2 61      5    7 -1.5
62 -1 62      5    7 -1.5
63  0 63      5    7 -1.5
```

Comment: What is the logic involved in assigning `span` and `set`? How does 1st value get rows 1-12, 2nd 13-27 and so on?

Comment: @RonakShah the `span` gives the range of each cycle, I am hence grabbing the max and mean in each cycle to find the range of it. `set` is the point around which the cycle oscillates, so if its perfectly symmetric, it should be zero, but since my data is not symmetric, I subtract the max of each cycle by the half of its span

Comment: Ok..but it is still not clear to me how you decide 1st cycle to be from 1-12

Comment: The definition I would like the code to understand (how I am deciding the datapoints that belong to each cycle) is: 1. find the peaks and valleys. 2. calculate the span and set point between each peak and valley. 3. group all the data points that come before the set point as one cycle. this means from the beginning to the first set point would be cycle one. now I understand that the set point is a mean value and might not exist in the data set. So in the code needs to select the points that are less than or equal to the set point. Does this make sense? @RonakShah

Comment: But the question remains, how a cycle is defined first?

Comment: @AnilGoyal The data that I have is experimental, so I have already filtered the unwanted data. The first cycle is defined as the first data point to the one before the first set point. For example, considering the first set point is -1.0, the first cycle is defined at rows 1 to 12. Row 12 is selected as the end of the cycle because it occurs after the first peak and valley and is also equal or smaller than -1.0. The second cycle starts at row 13 and goes to row 27, because row 27 is has an amplitude of 0 which is less than or equal to 0.5, and occurs after the second peak and valley points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the definition of cycle I think your cycles should end at 12, 27, 36, 48 and 62nd rows and therefore be 6 cycles in all instead of 5.  Indeed there are 5 complete cycles only.

names of some the data/objects have been changed for sake of simplicity and differentiation-

## Given objects

```
df_a <- data.frame(a = c(0,1,2,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-2,-1,
                      0,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-2,-1,
                      0,1,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,2,1,
                      0,-1,-2,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,2,1,
                      0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-3,-2,-1,0))
df_a$b <- seq(1,length(df_a$a),1)
df_a
my_max <- findPeaks(df_a$a)
my_min <- findValleys(df_a$a)


span <- df_a[my_max-1,]$a-df_a[my_min-1,]$a
set <-  df_a[my_max,]$a - span/2
```

## Code proposed for cycle

```
# generate a for loop to calculate end of cycle

my_vec <- NULL # create a null vector

#create a my_vec through for loop
for(i in seq_along(my_max)){
  my_vec[i] <- which(df_a$b > max(my_max[i], my_min[i]) & df_a$a >= set[i])[1]
  }

library(tidyverse) # for cumsum function
#create cycle column
df_a$cycle <- rev(cumsum(rev(df_a$b %in% my_vec)))
#check
> df_a
    a  b cycle
1   0  1     5
2   1  2     5
3   2  3     5
4   3  4     5
5   2  5     5
6   1  6     5
7   0  7     5
8  -1  8     5
9  -2  9     5
10 -3 10     5
11 -2 11     5
12 -1 12     5
13  0 13     4
14  1 14     4
15  2 15     4
16  3 16     4
17  4 17     4
18  3 18     4
19  2 19     4
20  1 20     4
21  0 21     4
22 -1 22     4
23 -2 23     4
24 -3 24     4
25 -2 25     4
26 -1 26     4
27  0 27     4
28  1 28     3
29  2 29     3
30  1 30     3
31  0 31     3
32 -1 32     3
33 -2 33     3
34 -3 34     3
35 -2 35     3
36 -1 36     3
37  0 37     2
38  1 38     2
39  2 39     2
40  3 40     2
41  2 41     2
42  1 42     2
43  0 43     2
44 -1 44     2
45 -2 45     2
46 -3 46     2
47 -2 47     2
48 -1 48     2
49  0 49     1
50  1 50     1
51  2 51     1
52  3 52     1
53  2 53     1
54  1 54     1
55  0 55     1
56 -1 56     1
57 -2 57     1
58 -3 58     1
59 -4 59     1
60 -3 60     1
61 -2 61     1
62 -1 62     1
63  0 63     0
```

Above code will generate cycle numbers in reverse.  If however, you'll need them in sequence, do this

```
df_a$cycle <- max(rev(cumsum(rev(df_a$b %in% my_vec))))+1-rev(cumsum(rev(df_a$b %in% my_vec)))

df_a

> df_a
    a  b cycle
1   0  1     1
2   1  2     1
3   2  3     1
4   3  4     1
5   2  5     1
6   1  6     1
7   0  7     1
8  -1  8     1
9  -2  9     1
10 -3 10     1
11 -2 11     1
12 -1 12     1
13  0 13     2
14  1 14     2
15  2 15     2
16  3 16     2
17  4 17     2
18  3 18     2
19  2 19     2
20  1 20     2
21  0 21     2
22 -1 22     2
23 -2 23     2
24 -3 24     2
25 -2 25     2
26 -1 26     2
27  0 27     2
28  1 28     3
29  2 29     3
30  1 30     3
31  0 31     3
32 -1 32     3
33 -2 33     3
34 -3 34     3
35 -2 35     3
36 -1 36     3
37  0 37     4
38  1 38     4
39  2 39     4
40  3 40     4
41  2 41     4
42  1 42     4
43  0 43     4
44 -1 44     4
45 -2 45     4
46 -3 46     4
47 -2 47     4
48 -1 48     4
49  0 49     5
50  1 50     5
51  2 51     5
52  3 52     5
53  2 53     5
54  1 54     5
55  0 55     5
56 -1 56     5
57 -2 57     5
58 -3 58     5
59 -4 59     5
60 -3 60     5
61 -2 61     5
62 -1 62     5
63  0 63     6
```

## old code

```
my_vec <- NULL

for(i in seq_along(my_max)){
  my_vec[1] <- 0
  my_vec[i+1] <- which(df_a$b > max(my_max[i], my_min[i]) & df_a$a >= set[i])[1]
  }
# generate column cycle as intended

df_a$cycle <- c(rep(1:length(my_max), diff(my_vec)), rep(length(my_max)+1, length(df_a$a)-length(rep(1:length(my_max), diff(my_vec)))))

    a  b cycle
1   0  1     1
2   1  2     1
3   2  3     1
4   3  4     1
5   2  5     1
6   1  6     1
7   0  7     1
8  -1  8     1
9  -2  9     1
10 -3 10     1
11 -2 11     1
12 -1 12     1
13  0 13     2
14  1 14     2
15  2 15     2
16  3 16     2
17  4 17     2
18  3 18     2
19  2 19     2
20  1 20     2
21  0 21     2
22 -1 22     2
23 -2 23     2
24 -3 24     2
25 -2 25     2
26 -1 26     2
27  0 27     2
28  1 28     3
29  2 29     3
30  1 30     3
31  0 31     3
32 -1 32     3
33 -2 33     3
34 -3 34     3
35 -2 35     3
36 -1 36     3
37  0 37     4
38  1 38     4
39  2 39     4
40  3 40     4
41  2 41     4
42  1 42     4
43  0 43     4
44 -1 44     4
45 -2 45     4
46 -3 46     4
47 -2 47     4
48 -1 48     4
49  0 49     5
50  1 50     5
51  2 51     5
52  3 52     5
53  2 53     5
54  1 54     5
55  0 55     5
56 -1 56     5
57 -2 57     5
58 -3 58     5
59 -4 59     5
60 -3 60     5
61 -2 61     5
62 -1 62     5
63  0 63     6
```

## Explanation of logic

- In order to create end-points of each cycle, I have started with a null vector.
- first element of this vector is taken as `0`
- another elements (with same counts) created with your cycle definition, thus making the elements in my_vec one extra than needed
- `my_vec` will have end points of each cycle
- diff(my_vec) will result in again same number of elements but each representing end points of each cycle
- rep(1:number of complete cycles, diff(my_vec) will result in generation of desired vector
- this vector will rersult in generation of complete cycles only.  Thereafter incomplete cycle number needs to be added.

You can thereafter join the columns already generated.

## complete output

```
df_b <- data.frame(cycle = 1:length(my_max))
df_b$span <- df_a[my_max-1,]$a-df_a[my_min-1,]$a
df_b$set <-  df_a[my_max,]$a - span/2

merge(df_a, df_b, by.x = "cycle", by.y = "cycle", all = T)
   cycle  a  b span  set
1      1  0  1    6 -1.0
2      1  1  2    6 -1.0
3      1  3  4    6 -1.0
4      1  2  5    6 -1.0
5      1  1  6    6 -1.0
6      1  2  3    6 -1.0
7      1 -1  8    6 -1.0
8      1 -2  9    6 -1.0
9      1 -3 10    6 -1.0
10     1  0  7    6 -1.0
11     1 -1 12    6 -1.0
12     1 -2 11    6 -1.0
13     2  0 13    7 -0.5
14     2  1 14    7 -0.5
15     2  2 15    7 -0.5
16     2  4 17    7 -0.5
17     2  3 18    7 -0.5
18     2  2 19    7 -0.5
19     2  3 16    7 -0.5
20     2  0 21    7 -0.5
21     2 -1 22    7 -0.5
22     2 -2 23    7 -0.5
23     2  1 20    7 -0.5
24     2 -2 25    7 -0.5
25     2 -1 26    7 -0.5
26     2  0 27    7 -0.5
27     2 -3 24    7 -0.5
28     3  1 28    5 -1.5
29     3  1 30    5 -1.5
30     3  0 31    5 -1.5
31     3 -1 32    5 -1.5
32     3  2 29    5 -1.5
33     3 -3 34    5 -1.5
34     3 -2 35    5 -1.5
35     3 -1 36    5 -1.5
36     3 -2 33    5 -1.5
37     4  1 38    6 -1.0
38     4  2 39    6 -1.0
39     4  3 40    6 -1.0
40     4  2 41    6 -1.0
41     4  1 42    6 -1.0
42     4  0 43    6 -1.0
43     4 -1 44    6 -1.0
44     4 -2 45    6 -1.0
45     4 -3 46    6 -1.0
46     4 -2 47    6 -1.0
47     4 -1 48    6 -1.0
48     4  0 37    6 -1.0
49     5  0 49    7 -1.5
50     5  2 51    7 -1.5
51     5  3 52    7 -1.5
52     5  2 53    7 -1.5
53     5  1 54    7 -1.5
54     5  0 55    7 -1.5
55     5 -1 56    7 -1.5
56     5 -2 57    7 -1.5
57     5 -3 58    7 -1.5
58     5 -4 59    7 -1.5
59     5 -3 60    7 -1.5
60     5 -2 61    7 -1.5
61     5 -1 62    7 -1.5
62     5  1 50    7 -1.5
63     6  0 63   NA   NA
```

## we can check it

```
library(tidyverse)

df_a %>% ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x=b, y=a, linetype = as.character(cycle)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I cannot tell why but I get an error when running the cycle line with my own data: `Error in rep(1:length(max.force), diff(min.force)) : 
  invalid 'times' argument` Here `max.force` is your `my_max` and `min.force` is your `my_min`I cannot tell why, the `times` values which are diff(min.force) are all positive

Comment: The second argument in rep is not min.force but my_vec. Please check

Comment: @MaralDorri, I have edited the formula for calculation of cycle.  See if it helps