# How to find all the minima in a graph?

Tags: python, data-visualization

I am trying to find all the minima in this graph.

[image: Graph]

But when I am writing this code it is giving many extra minima too and I want total 8 minima.

```
mini = []
for i in range(1, len(y)-1):
if y[i-1] >= y[i] and y[i] <= y[i+1]:
    mini.append(i)
print(mini)
```

Output

```
[2, 5, 7, 15, 20, 26, 30, 37, 40, 47, 50, 52, 59, 61, 64, 70, 76, 84, 89, 94, 96, 99, 107, 109, 117, 120, 122, 130, 134, 140, 144, 148, 154, 164, 169, 176]
```

And I want to cut my data according to these minimum values. Can somebody tell me what changes should I make in this code to achieve my goal?

Comment: Yes as you can see it is a sort of periodic graph so I just want to get the minimas after each complete cycle so I can divide the graph and the cycle and determine the stopping point of each cycle. And in this graph you can see that there are 7 full cycles according to which I want to get the minima. Can you please guide me on how can break the data using the minima too?

Comment: Do you have some knowledge of the period of your graph ahead of time? Here it looks like the period is a little over 50. A minimum over a number of values greater than one cycle but smaller than two cycles should fit what you're after, if you have a way of knowing what the period is.

Comment: Okay so there is no period. What I am trying to ask is the lowest point after each varying curve, the ones I have circled. Would it be possible to obtain them?

Comment: Okay I get it thank you. Is there is way to find the lowest points (peaks) in the graph

Comment: Try to understand this- What you are counting as a cycle must be based on some threshold value on y axis! What's that value? After the first circle, see there are three minima clearly which you have excluded.  But the logic of not accepting these three points of completion of cycle hasn't been explianed.

Comment: though not of python, still give this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65801769/group-data-in-a-dataframe-by-cycles/65840716#65840716) a read.

Comment: Can you please provide me some of your sample data?

Comment: Okay I understand what you are saying now. I will read this and try to understand what more criteria should I define to get these points. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Thanks :)  After this give some time to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66189356/vector-filling-true-or-false-based-on-the-given-conditions-in-r-without-cycle/66203464#66203464) too

Comment: Actually I am working on a video so the x axis is frames of the video and y is pixel intensities.

Comment: Superimposing moving average might suggest which minima should be selected.  Proper selection of moving average threshold would determine sensitivity.  And again, as others have suggested, periodicity is a key factor with this dataset I think.